# List of AdMob attributes used in xml and in extras

Tags: android, admob, adview

Searching through the web didn't give me the reference to neither the attributes which may be used when setting up **AdMob**'s `AdView` in xml, nor the valid values used as `AdRequest.extras`.

The official documentation on [AdView in XML](https://developers.google.com/mobile-ads-sdk/docs/android/banner_xml) gives just following example:

```
<com.google.ads.AdView android:id="@+id/adView"
                       android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                       android:layout_height="wrap_content"

                       ads:adUnitId="MY_AD_UNIT_ID"
                       ads:adSize="BANNER"
                       ads:testDevices="TEST_EMULATOR, TEST_DEVICE_ID"
                       ads:loadAdOnCreate="true"/>
```

While the [guide on extras](https://developers.google.com/mobile-ads-sdk/docs/bestpractices#adcolors) specifies just following values:

```
color_bg        Background color
color_bg_top    Gradient background color at top
color_border    Border color
color_link      Link text color
color_text      Text color
color_url       URL color
```

So, are these values the only possible way to customize (not considering `Targeting`) the `AdView` and `AdRequest` or are there any unmentioned values/attributes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The AdView also has an `ads:keywords` attribute which takes in a comma separated list of keywords.  AdMob doesn't use the keywords at all though - it just passes them to AdSense backfill if you have that enabled.

I'm not aware of any other extras that AdMob itself uses.  For those who are using DoubleClick for Publishers with AdMob, you can use the extras for custom targetting of your ad inventory.